# Detect whether CodeIgniter script is first started

Tags: php, codeigniter, installation

I am developing a CodeIgniter app that can be downloaded and self-hosted.
Like the most applications this should have an installation page.
The problem is I don't know how to detect whether it is installed or not, does anybody of you have an idea?

Comment: You might check the presence of the related tables in the DB, or the presence of an "install" directory which will be deleted after installation, or a config file properly structured, or variations along this lines

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how do you install it.

maybe you can set a db field on/off or 1/0 to check if codeigniter has been installed.